# Including two taxonomies in a permalink structure

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, permalinks

I am trying to get my head around the permalink structures on Wordpress sites, and I'm a bit stuck with what I'm trying to achieve:

My current permalink structure: **/%category%/%postname%/**

I have a custom-post type called 'city', and I want to create a structure like below:

**mydomain.com/asia/china/beijing**

So just to explain this structure:

**asia** - This is a term under a taxonomy called **'continent'**

**china** - This is a term under another taxonomy called **'country'**

**beijing** - This is the actual custom-post type post with title **'Beijing'**

So I basically have two taxonomies (continent and country) linking to my **'city'** post type. So the way I see it, I need a structure like this:

**mydomain.com/(taxonomy-continent)/(taxonomy-country)/(custom-post)**

But I cannot seem to figure out how to achieve this with the permalink structure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Is "country" a "sub-tax" inside your (hopefully hierarchical) taxonomy "continent"?

Comment: Oh right, silly me. I didn't think to create just one continent taxonomy and have the countries as sub-taxonomies. But it still doesn't solve the issue with my urls displaying the actual continent and country terms, rather than the taxonomy names themselves. e.g. at the moment I suspect it will display mydomain.com/continent/country/beijing whereas I want it to display mydomain.com/asia/china/beijing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need these two taxonomies. Just make your custom post type for places hierarchical and set countries and continents as parents. WordPress will build your permalinks then exactly as you want it.

After you’ve created the first post you get a selector for page parents from which you can choose:

[image]

Comment: Oh right, so do you mean create a custom post type called 'cities' for example, and then create countries page and continents page and set them as parents of that custom post type?

Comment: @remi90 Yes, exactly. You’ll need very similar meta data anyway: population size, geo coordinates, above mean sea level, spoken languages … it is much easier to implement this for _one_ custom post type.

Comment: But after a quick google search, it seems that setting a PAGE as the parent of a custom post-type is not very straight-forward, and Wordpress does not support it. Let me know if you have a way around this though?

Comment: You make the CPT hierarchical (`'hierarchical' => TRUE`), create a CPT page for the continent, a second for the country with the continent as parent, and a third for the city with the country as parent.

Comment: Sorry to be pain. I understand what you are saying in your comment - that I should create a custom post type thats hierarchical and then create a page for each continent (asia, europe, africa), for each country (china, england, ghana) and make it's parent the continent, and then create a page for each city (beijing) and make the country the parent. But where exactly can I do that? I don't have the option to set page parents or anything within my custom post type admin area. I must be missing something obvious?

Comment: @remi90 I have added a screenshot. You get a selector for parent posts after you have published the first one.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying Toscho, I actually confused myself as I only had one post and so obviously it didn't show the option to have a parent! Doh!

Comment: Yeah, like most native meta boxes this interface isn't very intuitive. Sooner or later you will probably build a replacement or filter at least the cities out. Otherwise the dropdown will get _very_ long.