# how to create child posts with parent post in wordpress?

Tags: posts, hierarchical

I want to create some future posts under one parent post, in that case in think **relationship in WordPress** posts is better option for me. So anyone who know about my question.

Comment: You can create [hierarchical post types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41024/why-does-a-custom-post-type-need-the-hierarchical-args-setting).

Answer (score -1):

first you can know the relationship between child post and parent post try to figure it out or just try this code

```
     $query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_parent' => get_theID(),
    'posts_per_page' => 3, //shows only 3 children. If you want to show all of them, comment this line
));
while($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    /*Output the child markup here*/
    the_content(); //Outputs child's content as it is
}
wp_reset_query();
```

?>